# Nextpeer ranking display not showing on first game

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nextpeer

I am using Nextpeer in my game for multiplayer. I am building it in Cocos2d 3 for the iphone and ipad. The Nextpeer ranking display UI does not show up on the first multiplayer game played on each session. Although it does show up the first time on another one of my games. The only difference is that this new game is in landscape mode.

What I have tried:

- using [Nextpeer enableRankingDisplay:YES]; at the start of the game
- I have set the Nextpeer start default orientation to a specific landscape mode
- I have checked and went over the different kinds of settings when I init Nextpeer to see if they have anything specific for landscape
- I have emailed Nextpeer support and they have no record of this problem for landscape mode

This bug only happens on the first multiplayer game, the UI shows up every other time. It also seems to show up if I open the Nextpeer dashboard, close it and then enter a game. It seems to be just the first time the dashboard is opened.

The only thing I changed when switching to landscape is the Nextpeer bundle, from portrait to landscape. Is there anything I could of missed when switching orientations? Has anyone else seen this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Your Xcode project should have only one resource bundle, so make sure you referenced only the landscape bundle.

Comment: I only have the landscape bundle in the project which is linked in the resource bundle. It also has been clean built multiple times since I switched the portrait bundle out for the landscape one.